# $E[X^T (Y-Z)] = E[X^T] E[Y-Z]$ but what about $E[(X^T (Y-Z))^2]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence, matrix, random-vector

Let $X, Y$, and $Z$ be random vectors with $X$ independent of $Y$ and $Z$. Due to the independence we have
$$
E[X^T (Y-Z)] = E[X^T] E[Y-Z].
$$
But what what $E[(X^T (Y-Z))^2]$? Is it possible to decompose this in a similar fashion so that we separate the $X$ and from the $Y$ and $Z$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E} \left[ (X^T (Y-Z))^2 \right] &= \mathbf{E} \left[ X^T (Y-Z) (Y - Z)^T X \right] \\
&= \mathbf{E} \left[ \textbf{Tr} \left\{ X^T (Y-Z) (Y - Z)^T X \right\} \right] \\
&= \mathbf{E} \left[ \textbf{Tr} \left\{ X X^T (Y-Z) (Y - Z)^T \right\} \right] \\
&= \textbf{Tr} \left\{\mathbf{E} \left[  X X^T (Y-Z) (Y - Z)^T \right] \right\} \\
&= \textbf{Tr} \left\{\mathbf{E} \left[  X X^T \right] \mathbf{E}\left[(Y-Z) (Y - Z)^T \right] \right\}
\end{align}

Comment: Thats great thanks!

Comment: I just asked a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499362/separating-x-from-y-and-z-in-ext-y-zp-for-p-3-and-4). Basically is it possible to separate the $X$ from the $Y$ and $Z$ for higher powers.