# Separating $X$ from $Y$ in $E[(X^T Y))^p]$ for $p = 3$ and $4$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, independence, matrix

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random vectors with $X$ independent of $Y$. When dealing with terms of the form $E[(X^T Y)^p]$ for $p \ge 1$, it is very useful to be able to separate the $X$ from the $Y$.

For $p=1,2$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
E[X^T Y] &= E[X^T] E[Y], \\
E[(X^T Y)^2] &= Tr \left\{E \left[  X X^T \right] E\left[YY^T \right] \right\}.
\end{align}
$$
The second expression was proven [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498855/ext-y-z-ext-ey-z-but-what-about-ext-y-z2). I am wondering it is possible to obtain similar expressions for the cases $p=3$ and $p=4$ as some applications require us to go to fourth order:
$$
\begin{align}
E[(X^T Y)^3] &= \quad ? \\
E[(X^T Y)^4] &= \quad ? \\ 
\end{align}
$$
Does anyone know if it is possible to derive expressions that separate the $X$ from $Y$ in these cases? (Maybe a pattern will then become clear for all $p \ge 1$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that for nonnegative integer values $P$, it is in principle possible, but gets progressively more complicated as $P$ increases. To this end, one can write

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E} \left[ \left( X^T Y \right)^P\right] &= \mathbf{E} \left[ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^D X_i Y_i \right)^P \right] \\
&= \mathbf{E} \left[  \sum_{i_1 = 1}^D \sum_{i_2 = 1}^D \cdots \sum_{i_P = 1}^D \prod_{p = 1}^P X_{i_p} Y_{i_p} \right] \\
&= \sum_{i_1 = 1}^D \sum_{i_2 = 1}^D \cdots \sum_{i_P = 1}^D \mathbf{E} \left[   \prod_{p = 1}^P X_{i_p} Y_{i_p} \right] \\
&= \sum_{i_1 = 1}^D \sum_{i_2 = 1}^D \cdots \sum_{i_P = 1}^D \mathbf{E} \left[   \prod_{p = 1}^P X_{i_p}  \right] \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[   \prod_{p = 1}^P  Y_{i_p} \right].
\end{align}

However, the expressions like $\prod_{p = 1}^P X_{i_p}$ become more challenging to characterize concisely in closed form as $P$ grows.

For a concrete example, consider when $P = 3$, and assume that the coordinates of $X$ and $Y$ are each iid. The above expression can then be simplified to

\begin{align}
\sum_{i_1 = 1}^D \sum_{i_2 = 1}^D \sum_{i_3 = 1}^D \mathbf{E} \left[   \prod_{p = 1}^3 X_{i_p}  \right] \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[   \prod_{p = 1}^3  Y_{i_p} \right] &= D \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ X^3 \right] \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ Y^3 \right] \\
&+ 3D(D - 1) \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ X \right] \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ X^2 \right] \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ Y \right] \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ Y^2 \right] \\
&+ D(D-1)(D-2) \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ X \right] ^3 \cdot \mathbf{E} \left[ Y \right]^3.
\end{align}

Comment: Do you know if there are nice closed form expressions for the $P=3$ and $4$ cases?

Comment: This general result simplifies by means of multinomial coefficients.  That reduces the expression to sums over integer partitions of $P.$ This rapidly gets more and more complicated as $P$ increases.

Comment: The pattern for general $P$ is very interesting but my main concern is the $P=3$ and $4$ cases. I'm wondering are there 'nice' expressions for these cases like the $P=1$ and $2$ cases.

Comment: @Bertus101: Finite summations of finite products is already "closed form" (though not particulary simple looking in this case).

Comment: How do we interpret powers of random vectors such as $E[X^3]$. Does this notation mean $E[X^3] = E[X^T X X^T]$ so that $E[X^3]$ would then be a random vector and $E[X^3]\cdot E[Y^3]$ would be a dot product of two random vectors? Similarly with $E[X]^3$, does this mean $E[X]^T E[X] E[X]^T$?

Comment: I have made the assumption that the coordinates of $X$ and $Y$ are each iid, so $\mathbf{E} \left[ X^3 \right] = \mathbf{E} \left[ X_1^3 \right]$, etc.

Comment: Ah ok I see now. What about the case when they are not iid as that is actually what I am interested in? In your answer to my previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499362/separating-x-from-y-in-ext-yp-for-p-3-and-4) the fact that you proved $E[(X^T(Y-Z))^2] = Tr[XX^T]E[(Y-Z)(Y-Z)^T]$ was very useful to me as when $Z$ is the mean of $Y$, I was able to use $E[(Y-Z)(Y-Z)^T] = \text{Cov}[Y,Y]$ and account for the covariances between the elements of $Y$. So do you know if there is a nice formula for the non-iid $P=3$ case?

Comment: Again - in principle, such an expression exists, but in practice, it is unlikely to be easy to work with. Inevitably, you will end up either having to do some combinatorics or some advanced linear algebra (e.g. using tensors).